# Compile GCC Inline Assembly into Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I'm having trouble compiling this GCC inline assembly to Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 assembly

**GCC inline assembly:**

```
__asm__(
    "smull %0, %1, %2, %3     \n\t"
    "mov   %0, %0,     LSR #16 \n\t"
    "add   %1, %0, %1, LSL #16  \n\t"
    : "=&r"(lo), "=&r"(hi)
    : "r"(rb), "r"(ra));
```

The compiler says:

**error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ':'**

The complete function is:

```
static __inline Word32 mull(Word32 a, Word16 b)
{
    register Word32 ra = a;
    register Word32 rb = b;
    Word32 lo, hi;

    __asm__(
        "smull %0, %1, %2, %3     \n\t"
        "mov   %0, %0,     LSR #16 \n\t"
        "add   %1, %0, %1, LSL #16  \n\t"
        : "=&r"(lo), "=&r"(hi)
        : "r"(rb), "r"(ra));

    return hi;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The MS extension for inline asm is `__asm`, and its syntax is generally very different.  Also I'm not so sure it supports inline asm on ARM.  (Might need a separate .asm file.)

Comment: Could you please try to translate it to MS extension? @asveikau

Comment: Just one more small note: In general, if some function or call starts with an underscore (like `__asm__()`) you should always assume that it won't work on other compilers, since it's not part of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does not support ARM inline assembly.  See: [Inline assembly is not supported on the ARM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx). You will need to either reverse-engineer the assembly code to C, or use a separate assembler and link this as a separate function.

It looks like this function just does a 32 x 32 -> 64 bit signed multiply and then shifts the 64 bit result right by 16 bits and truncates it to 32 bits:

```
static __inline Word32 mull(Word32 a, Word16 b)
{
    return (Word32)(((Word64)a * (Word64)b) >> 16);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the reverse-engineer to C will be a solution but how can I do that? As I understand the assembly multiply two parameters and then shifts 16-bit right and 16-bit left, I don't know what would be the C equivalent source code :(

Comment: Just read the descriptions for the ARM instructions and then implement them in C. You can use the gcc code to validate your C interpretation. See: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHBJEHG.html

Comment: I tried to convert it to C but Im very confused about assembly instructions, any guide will be appreciated :)

Comment: OK - I've converted the code to C and I think it's correct, but you will need to test it.